# UIAlertView alertView.cancelButtonIndex = -1; Not Working

Tags: ios7, uialertview

I am trying to create an AlertView which does not have a cancel button.

This is the code I have tried:

```
    alertView.cancelButtonIndex = -1;
```

It does not seem to work with iOS 7.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1) With using this code pressing "Do something button" can do some action but will not lead to `alertView` hiding

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"The message."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Do something", nil] show];

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    return NO; 
}
```

2) With using this code there will be no buttons on the `alertView`(*I think this is what you actually need*)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"The message."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
```